# Rewrite equation of conic section using Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Given the quadratic equation $2x^2 - 4xy + 5y^2 = 36$, which defines a solution set for a conic section in the (x,y)-plane. How do I rewrite this equation, using theory of Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors, into the form $a(x')^2 + b(y')^2 = 36$. Where (x', y') are the coordinates against a different basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and these basis vectors are perpendicular to each other.

What I have tried so far is writing $2x^2 - 4xy + 5y^2$ in a matrix as follows: $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2 \\ -2 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$. From this matrix I calculated the Eigenvalues 6 and 1, which give the Eigenvectors (1, -2) and (2, 1). But from then on I am stuck, can anyone help me in solving this problem?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to write $A := \pmatrix{2 & -2 \\ -2 & 5}$ in the form $U^\top \pmatrix{6 & 0 \\ 0 & 1} U$, where $U$ is orthogonal. You can form $U$ by normalising your (orthogonal) basis of eigenvectors. Then $x^\top A x = (Ux)^\top \pmatrix{6 & 0 \\ 0 & 1} (Ux)$, which will quickly lead you to your answer.

Comment: My class hasn't yet gotten to orthogonal systems, could you maybe explain further?

Comment: Given the question asks for basis vectors that are orthogonal to each other, and specifies using eigenvalues/eigenvectors, I don't think I'm referring to anything you haven't covered yet. I'm saying, diagonalise $A$. Normally, this means you can write $A = P^{-1} D P$, where $D$ is diagonal, consisting of the eigenvalues of $A$, and $P$ contains the eigenvectors of $A$ as columns. When $A$ is symmetric, the eigenvectors are orthogonal. If they are length $1$, then $P^{-1} = P^\top$. So, just divide the eigenvectors by their lengths, to form $U$.

Comment: Thank you, I have found $A = P^-1DP$, namely A = $\begin{pmatrix} 1/sqrt(5) & 2/sqrt(5) \\ -2/sqrt(5) & 1/sqrt(5) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 6 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1/sqrt(5) & -2/sqrt(5) \\ 2/sqrt(5) & 1/sqrt(5) \end{pmatrix}$. But how do I go further from this?

Comment: So, your $P$ is the $U$ in the original comment. If you let $\pmatrix{x' \\y'} = U \pmatrix{x\\y}$, you should find that $\pmatrix{x' \\y'}^\top \pmatrix{6 & 0 \\ 0 & 1} \pmatrix{x' \\y'} = 2x^2 - 4xy + 5y^2$, but will also be in the form $a(x')^2 + by')^2$.

Comment: I understand now that the matrix multiplication would lead to $2x^2 - 4xy + 5y^2$, but I'm not quite sure I understand how I would go to find $a(x')^2 + b(y')^2$.

Comment: As I said, $\pmatrix{x' \\y'} = U \pmatrix{x\\y}$. Multiply that out to get $x'$ and $y'$.

Comment: So that would be $\begin{pmatrix} x/\sqrt(5) + 2y/\sqrt(5) \\ -2x/\sqrt(5) + 1y/sqrt(5) \end{pmatrix}$, which would make the final expression $a(x/\sqrt(5) + 2y/\sqrt(5))^2 + b(-2x/\sqrt(5) + y/\sqrt(5))^2$, correct?

Comment: Right. See if you can find $a$ and $b$ now.

Comment: For a = 6 and b = 1, the Eigenvalues, the expression would be equivalent to $2x^2 -4xy + 5y^2$. So I believe that final answer would be $6(x/\sqrt(5) + 2y/\sqrt(5))^2 + (-2x/\sqrt(5) + y/\sqrt(5))^2$.

Comment: Indeed. Note that these are just the eigenvalues. Back in my first comment, I noted that $x^\top A x = (Ux)^\top \pmatrix{6 & 0 \\ 0 & 1} (Ux)$, which becomes $\pmatrix{x'\\y'}^\top \pmatrix{6 & 0 \\ 0 & 1} \pmatrix{x'\\y'} = 6(x')^2 + (y')^2$. So, it should make sense.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for the help and the patience. I better understand the first comment you made now.

Comment: No problem. Good on you for continuing to work through it.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed the equation can be rewritten in the matrix form

$$ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}^T Q \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} = 36$$

where  $Q = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2 \\ -2 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$.  The question asks both that equation be of the form $ax'^2 + by'^2 = 36$ which can be rewritten has

$$ \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y'\end{pmatrix}^T \Lambda \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y'\end{pmatrix} = 36$$
for some diagonal matrix $\Lambda.$

Hence it seems like an obvious choice to diagonalize the matrix $Q$ and place ourselves in a basis of eigenvectors.

Let us see where this leads !

The matrix $Q$ has eigenvalues $6$ and $1$ with corresponding eigenvectors $(1,-2)$ and $(2,1).$ Let $P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and we have
$P\Lambda P^{-1} = Q$ so the initial equation can be rewritten as

$$ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}^TP \Lambda P^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} = 36.$$

This is almost what we want but not quite. Indeed we want

$$ P^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}^TP =  \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y'\end{pmatrix}^T \quad \text{i.e.} \quad P^T \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y'\end{pmatrix} $$

Hence we would like $P$ such that $PP^T = I$. That is we would like $P$ such that the columns of $P$ are orthonormal.

---

Since $Q$ is a symmetric matrix with real coefficients we know that the eigenvectors of $Q$ corresponding to different eigenvalues are always orthogonal. Hence to solve the problem we must find a basis of eigenvectors, normalize them and then do the above.